# How can I exit a click function or prevent the function from triggering until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal:**
I want to be able to add comments onto images and use their X,Y coordinates to save the comment and display for later.

**Expected Result:**
I want a user to click on a "New Comment" button which enables "Comment Mode" and displays a form. If a user clicks away from the form, I want the form to hide and "Comment Mode" to become disabled until the user clicks "New Comment" again. If "New Comment" is pressed again, repeat the above.

**Actual Result:**
The snippet of code currently allows a user to click "New Comment". Once clicked the `commentMode()` function is triggered and listens for a click on the `#imageWrapper`. If the user clicks away, the form is hidden - but when I press "New Comment" again, the form remains hidden.

```
function commentMode() {
          imageWrapper.toggleClass('new-comment-pointer'); // changes cursor to show its active
          imageWrapper.click(function(e) { // on clicking the image
            newComment = !newComment; // newComment is true
            console.log(newComment);
            if(newComment) { // if newComment is true, show the form near the click
              getCoordinates(e, $('#imageWrapper'));
              form.show().css({'left': formX, 'top': formY});
              form.find('textarea').focus();
              form.find('#xAxis').val(x); // x is from the getCoordinates
              form.find('#yAxis').val(y); // y is from the getCoordinates
            } else { // if newComment is false, hide the form and turn stop imageWrapper.click
              form.hide();
              imageWrapper.removeClass('new-comment-pointer');
              newComment = !newComment;
              return; //stop listening for click
            }
            return; 
          });
        }
```

https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/YzzPEqw

Comment: the issue is, every time you click new comment you add another click handler to `imageWrapper.click` so you end up with that code running multiple times on each click

Comment: Actually, the problem is not that @Bravo, it's just that your `else` block is toggling the newComment value and then you're re-toggling that again in the begining of your onClick function.

Comment: @Bravo, is it bad that the code runs multiple times? Is there another solution that doesn't require it to fire multiple times?

Comment: @Davo, removing it allows it to be re-enabled. But now the form never goes away!

Comment: Yes Lachie, you need to refactor your code, it's not working with the right logic. The first thing is that you need to define the `newComment ` variable outside the onclick function, as a global variable basic.

Comment: Thanks @Davo. I'll have another crack at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Davo mentioned in the comments, I attempted to refactor the code. I started by cleaning up the code into functions and not nesting click events. Whilst refactoring, I used `console.log`'s to help me identify when the `commentMode` was active - then triggered the `showForm()` or `hideForm()` functions. For a working example: https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/bGGNYmK

```
$(function () {

        var imageWrapper = $('#imageWrapper');
        var form = $('.new-comment');
        var x, y, formX, formY;
        var newComment = true;
        var commentMode = false;

        $('#newComment').click(function() {
          imageWrapper.toggleClass('new-comment-pointer');
          commentMode = !commentMode;
          //console.log('newComment');
        });

        $('#imageWrapper').click(function(e) {
          if(commentMode) {
            //console.log('commentMode: true');
            showForm(e);
          } else {
            //console.log('commentMode: false');
            hideForm();
          }
        });

        function showForm(e) {
          getCoordinates(e, imageWrapper);
          form.show().css({'left': formX, 'top': formY});
          form.find('textarea').focus();
          form.find('#xAxis').val(x); // x is from the getCoordinates
          form.find('#yAxis').val(y); // y is from the getCoordinates
        }

        function hideForm() {
          form.hide();
        }

        function getCoordinates(e, image) {
          var offset = image.offset();
          x = e.pageX - offset.left;
          y = e.pageY - offset.top;
          formX = x + 50;
          formY = y + 20;
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why everybody make it complicated.
First give the form and the button a id. Then define a default form css class which is hidden.Define another ones which makes it visible some kind of:

```
<style>
  .invisible   {
    display:none;  
  }

.visible   {
    display:block !important;  
 }
</style>
```

Now we add a document listener which make things more simple instead fiddeling on whatever event...

```
document.addEventListener(" click ", function(event) {
//try to get a id even when the event element has not
// directly a id but maybee his parent the form
try {
   var id = event.target.id;
   if (id === "") {
      for (i = 0; i < event.path.length; i++) {
        id = event.path[i].id;
        if (id !== "") {
           if (id === "formid") {
            break;
           }
        }

    }
    } catch(ex){
       console.log(ex);
       return;
    } 
    var form=document.getElementById("formid");
    switch(id){
        case "showcommehtbuttonid":
        case "formid":
              form.classList.add("visible");
        break;
        default:
              form.classList.remove("visible"); 
    }
 }
```

The toggle state has a disadvantage in your case - complicate to handle. Works best by a simple id and button. There is no doubt about then. Adding and removing handlers also makes no real sense. Either the user clicks on the form or the button and the form becomes visible. Or he clicks something else. In this case no id or the "wrong" id will be chosen. In this case the default switch rule make the form invisible. The thing is untested and might need some minor tweaks. And best - in the event handler you can now also add very simple more actions.

Comment: I do not know why i get downvoted- that will exactly do what he wants. His damn toggle state gets mixed up. And BTW: Ive not made this funny textarea which is a pain in the .... So i need at least a few trys or minutes to made it. But hey feel great !

Comment: I didn't downvote but I am confused about this. I currently show and hide the form successfully using JQuery `hide()` and `show()`. I agree my toggle state is complicated. Your code seems more complicated and I can't match that into what I've got?

Comment: it is not :) I just use plain javascript to add a global event listener. Then i know this listener is THERE ;) I add a for next loop over the bubbeling chain cause i do not know hat you has in the form. The user might click wherever. So in this case it runs the event chain up until it gets the form id. Than its happy. visible state is set even it might not be needed. If the user clicks wherever this chain will not work. So it becomes invisible. If the user clicks the button the same handler will also show this form. Thats not complicated thats stupid simple rocksolid :)

Comment: And also no Toggle state can get mixed up ;) There is no toggle. There is either on or off ;)

Answer (score -1):

Working and tested  :) ! Ok we could work on the page style quite a bit but :d 
Look how simple the whole page looks also. I do not have to fight with jquery for this little task :) I set also the autofocus just by plain html.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>

        <html>

            <head>
                <title>Untitled</title>
                <style>
                    .invisible {
                        display: none;
                        border: 1px solid red;
                    }

                    .visible {
                        display: block !important;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>

            <body>

                <form id="formid" class="invisible">
                    <h1>Form</h1>
                    <input type="text" name="size" autofocus>

                </form>

                <hr>
                <input type="button" value="click" id="showcommentbuttonid">
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                                 try {
                                    var id = event.target.id;
                                    if (id === "") {
                                        for (i = 0; i < event.path.length; i++) 
                                          {
                                            id = event.path[i].id;
                                            if (id !== "") {
                                                if (id === "formid") {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (ex) {
                                    console.log(ex);
                                    return;
                                }
                                var form = document.getElementById("formid");
                                switch (id) {
                                    case "showcommentbuttonid":
                                    case "formid":
                                        form.classList.add("visible");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        form.classList.remove("visible");
                                }

                            }
                            )
                </script>
            </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Try to get it mixed up ;)

Comment: Have you seen the CodePen at the bottom? https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/YzzPEqw

Comment: Lachie i want to help (as a hobby or as a thank for the help i get here sometimes) - not do other peoples job for free :) Sure if you can afford 200 EUR per hour i might think about :) That is what my boss usually put on the bills. We are also really great on railroad bridges or concrete structures *grin*